# C++ Allegro rotate group of line()

Tags: c++, allegro

I would like to roatate a line() object which I have created using Allegro 4 library.

```
    circle( buffer, xm=xm+xx, ym=ym+yy, r=r+q, c0);
    line( buffer, xm   , ym-30, xm+15, ym-15, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm+15, ym-15, xm+5, ym-15, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm+5, ym-15, xm+5, ym+30, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm+5, ym+30, xm-5, ym+30, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm-5, ym+30, xm-5, ym-15, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm-5, ym-15, xm-15, ym-15, c0 );
    line( buffer, xm-15, ym-15, xm   , ym-30, c0 );
```

Those line creates an arrow inside a circle. I would like to spin that arrow within that circle.

Comment: `sin` and `cos` might help.

Answer (score 1):

It's basic geometry, really.

```
newX = x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta)
newY = y*cos(theta) + x*sin(theta)
```

Will rotate points `x` and `y` by angle `theta` from the origin (0, 0) and stores the new coordinates in `newX` and `newY`. Extending this to rotate from a center is as easy as subtracting the center coordinates off the `x` and `y` coordinates and then adding again to the result:

```
newX = (x-centerX)*cos(theta) - (y-centerY)*sin(theta) + centerX
newY = (y-centerY)*cos(theta) + (x-centerX)*sin(theta) + centerY
```

So the function you will be calling on **each** point of the arrow would be something like this:

```
void rotate(float x, float y, float r, 
            float theta, float centerX, float centerY, 
            float &newX, float &newY){
    newX = (x-centerX)*cos(theta) - (y-centerY)*sin(theta) + centerX;
    newY = (y-centerY)*cos(theta) + (x-centerX)*sin(theta) + centerY;
}
```